# Socket disconnected after a message, (Connection refused by remote host), using python

Tags: python, sockets, azure

I have uploaded my python socket, (cloud service project), on azure ,and when ever I connected to Hercules client side socket ....after a message or two, connection closed by remote host... forcefully...?

### Server Code

```
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol
from twisted.internet import reactor
import SocketServer
class IphoneChat(Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        self.factory.clients.append(self)
        print('clients are'), self.factory.clients                  
    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        self.factory.clients.remove(self)        
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        msg = ""
        msg =  data.strip()
        for c in self.factory.clients:
            c.message(msg)                  
    def message(self, message):
        self.transport.write(message + '\n')        

print ('Iphone Chat server startedd')
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = IphoneChat
factory.clients = []
reactor.listenTCP(9073, factory)
reactor.run()
```

Comment: Is the project run as worker role or only run on Azure VM instance?

Comment: yes ,as worker role....?

Comment: in my solution i have two project one is worker role and  second is python cloud service , worker role as statup project before publishing to azure....

Comment: Which is this project?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue on my environment, but failed. Base on my experience, we often pay attention to 3 points if we use socket in azure worker role.

1. Open input TCP port. If we open a port as listener port, we'd better to add this port into the endpoints setting.
   [image]
2. Considered the worker role status, I suggest we can code logic into the `while True` loop function, as following,

   ```
   while True:
       reactor.listenTCP(65534, f)
       print "server run"
       reactor.run()
       sleep(1.0)
   ```
3. According to the error message, I guess the reason is that azure load balancer will kill the idle connection in 240s. I recommend you can refer to this [blog](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/08/14/new-configurable-idle-timeout-for-azure-load-balancer/) to configure your `idleTimeoutInMinutes` value.

Please try to check your project and configuration. Any further findings, please let me know.

Comment: i reset the configuration above as you said , but now i cannot connect to socket  virtual ip that is 23.96.57.211:9073 ? TCP connection time out

Comment: on your above mentioned BLOG by default the idle time is 4 minutes....but the issue is my connection lost with in several seconds....?

Comment: I will dig into it. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: @salmanrafiq, Sorry for delay in this issue and thanks for your patience. My colleague and I couldn't reproduce this issue, Could you please open a service request and directly work with support team?

Comment: what support team ? and how?

Comment: You can login on Azure management Portal. Click "your account" on right-top of portal=>> Select "Contact Microsoft Support"==>> click "New Support Request".